# One IDE for running a DApp

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

Is there one IDE that can be used to run a DApp ? I have the backend (solidity) and trying to build the front-end for it.(So the IDE should help me to build the front-end side as well as run the entire DApp with solidity )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Truffle Framework](https://truffleframework.com/) with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

This is a good place to get started: [Ethereum Pet Shop](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop)

And this too: [Configuring Visual Studio code for Ethereum Blockchain development](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/configuring-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Check out this [other link](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/configuring-visual-studio-code) too. (Edited into my main post)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do both with the same IDE you can use [Superblocks Lab](https://lab.superblocks.com/)

It allows you to live edit your DApp with instant feedback on the visuals and the contracts. You can also take the rendered source directly from the GUI and publish it.

Stay super!

/Javi